# Image Mosaic JDBC plugin for multiple tiles

Tags: postgis, geoserver, image-mosaic

I want to publish a large raster (10000 km², 0.5m resolution). My original data is several tiles of 5km².

I've merge all tiles and published an unique raster file with Image Mosaic JDBC Plugin. But is it possible to indicate in my mosaic table in postgres several tiles ? And would it be more efficient than publish an unique raster file, even if it pyramidize ?

I tried with 2 tiles, but just the first was published, even if the coordinates was computed on the mosaic table.

Comment: do you mean your mosaic only has one tile?

Comment: No, because I make 100pxX100px tiles with raster2pgsql, in several pyramid level, but from one only tiff file. I have a list of tables like mytiff, o_2_mytiff, o_4_mytiff ... But can I have several upload tiff in my table ? like myfirsttiff, o_2_myfirsttiff, o_4_myfirsttiff, mysecondtiff, o_2_mysecondtiff, o_4_mysecondtiff ... myntiff, o_2_myntiff, o_4_myntiff ?